# Swift NSStream delegate; reading is not working; stream func

Tags: swift, tcp, uiviewcontroller, delegates, nsstream

Hi I have been working on this code now for a while and I cannot figure out why my stream func is not being called?

I am building a joystick and it requires user interaction and it sends data but its not receiving data from server

can anyone see what the problem is?

I have attached my swift code and my python server

thanks!

```
import Darwin
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Dispatch

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var joystickMove: Joystick!
    @IBOutlet private weak var joystickRotate: Joystick!

    private var joystick = Joystick()
    private var contour = Contours()
    private var contour_index: Int = 0

    private var socket = Connection(address: "000.000.0.000" as CFString, port: 7041)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createJoystick()
        createContours()
        createButton()
    }

    private func createJoystick() {

        let n: CGFloat = 100.0
        let x: CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2) - (n/2.0)
        let y: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - (UIScreen.main.bounds.height/4.0)

        self.joystick.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: n, height: n)
        self.joystick.backgroundColor =  UIColor.clear

        self.joystick.substrateColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.joystick.substrateBorderColor = UIColor.gray
        self.joystick.substrateBorderWidth = 1.0
        self.joystick.stickSize = CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
        self.joystick.stickColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.joystick.stickBorderColor = UIColor.black
        self.joystick.stickBorderWidth = 2.0
        self.joystick.fade = 0.5

        var packet = ""

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { // do some task

            self.joystick.trackingHandler = { (data) -> () in

                let power = sqrt(pow(Double(data.velocity.x), 2.0) + pow(Double(data.velocity.y), 2.0))
                let theta = atan2(Double(-data.velocity.y), Double(data.velocity.x))
                let degrees = theta * (180.0 / M_PI)

                if degrees >= 55 && degrees <= 125 { // move forward
                    packet = "\(1) \(1) \(power) \(power)"
                } else if degrees >= -125 && degrees <= -55 { // move backwards
                    packet = "\(-1) \(-1) \(power) \(power)"
                } else if degrees >= -55 && degrees <= 55 { // turn right
                    packet = "\(1) \(-1) \(power) \(power)"
                } else if (degrees >= 125 && degrees <= 180) && (degrees >= -180 && degrees <= -125) { // turn left
                    packet = "\(-1) \(1) \(power) \(power)"
                }

                self.socket.connect()

                let sent = self.socket.sendMessage(message: packet)

                if sent {
                    print("packet sent!\n \(packet)")
                }

                self.socket.changeWhenHasBytesAvailable = { str in
                    print("my-str: \(str)")
                }

                self.socket.disconnect()
            }

        }

        view.addSubview(joystick)
    }

    private func createContours() {
        let n: CGFloat = 350.0
        let x: CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2.0) - (n/2.0)
        let y: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - (UIScreen.main.bounds.height/4.0) - n - 100.0
        self.contour.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: n, height: n)
        self.contour.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        view.addSubview(self.contour)
    }

    private func createButton() {
        let width: CGFloat = 150.0
        let height: CGFloat = 75.0
        let x: CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2.0) - (width/2.0)
        let y: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - (UIScreen.main.bounds.height/4.0) - width

        let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        button.setTitle("Contour Views", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.tag = 1
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc private func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        var btnsendtag: UIButton = sender
        if btnsendtag.tag == 1 {
            self.contour_index = (self.contour_index + 1) % 2
            switch self.contour_index {
            case 0:
                for index in 0...356 {
                    if self.contour.distx[index] != -1 && self.contour.disty[index] != -1 {
                        self.contour.circles[index].alpha = 0
                    }
                }
            case 1:
                for index in 0...356 {
                    if self.contour.distx[index] != -1 && self.contour.disty[index] != -1 {
                        self.contour.circles[index].alpha = 1
                    }
                }
            default:
                for index in 0...356 {
                    if self.contour.distx[index] != -1 && self.contour.disty[index] != -1 {
                        self.contour.circles[index].alpha = 1
                        UIColor.cyan.setFill()
                        self.contour.lines[index].fill()
                        self.contour.lines[index].stroke()
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { // do some task
//            self.socket.connect()
//            var packet = "1 1 0 0"
//            let sent = self.socket.sendMessage(message: packet)
//            if sent {
//                print("packet sent!\n \(packet)")
//            }
//            self.socket.disconnect()
        }
    }

    public func delayWithSeconds(_ seconds: Double, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
            completion()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
//        self.socket.disconnect()
    }
}
```

//

```
import Foundation

class Connection: NSObject, StreamDelegate {

    private var inputStream: InputStream!
    private var outputStream: OutputStream!

    private var my_address: CFString
    private var my_port: UInt32

    public var changeWhenHasBytesAvailable: ((String)->())?

    init (address: CFString, port:UInt32) {
        self.my_address = address
        self.my_port = port
        super.init()
    }

    public func connect() {

        var readStream:  Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
        var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, self.my_address, self.my_port, &readStream, &writeStream)

        self.inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
        self.outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

        self.inputStream.delegate = self
        self.outputStream.delegate = self

        self.inputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        self.outputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)

        self.inputStream.open()
        self.outputStream.open()

    }

    public func stream(aStream: Stream, handleEvent eventCode: Stream.Event) {

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { // do some task

            print("stream")

            if aStream === self.inputStream {
                switch eventCode {
                case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
                    print("available!")
                    var inputBuffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count:2048)
                    self.inputStream?.read(&inputBuffer, maxLength: 2048)
                    //call it in main queue
                    self.changeWhenHasBytesAvailable?(String(bytes: inputBuffer, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

                    //                    var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4096)
                    //                    while (inputStream!.hasBytesAvailable){
                    //                        var len = inputStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
                    //                        if(len > 0){
                    //                            var output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    //                            var output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: len, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
//                                                print("output: \(output)")
                    //                            if (output != ""){
                    //                                NSLog("server said: %@", output!)
                    //                            }
                    //                        } else {
                    //                            print("empty string from stream")
                    //                        }
                    //                    }


                    break
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public func sendMessage(message: String) -> Bool {
        var sent: Bool = false
        let buff = [UInt8](message.utf8)
        let result = self.outputStream.write(buff, maxLength: buff.count)

        if result != -1 {
            sent = true
        }
        return sent
    }

    public func disconnect() {
        self.inputStream.close()
        self.outputStream.close()

        //        self.inputStream.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        //        self.outputStream.remove(from: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    }

}
```

\\

```
import socketserver


class MyTCPSocketHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The RequesthHandler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client
    """

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client    
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024)
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address))

        packet = self.data.decode()
        print("decode-packet: {}".format(packet))

        self.request.sendto(bytes("11111111111111", 'utf-8'), self.client_address)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "", 7041
    socketserver.allow_reuse_address = True
    print("HOST: {}".format(HOST))
    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPSocketHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```